# jQuery show/hide expand/collapse with multiple nested div´s

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, expand, togglebutton

I want to display this:

```
<div class="column mcb-column one-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
<div class="column_attr clearfix align_right">
<h1 class="passos-metodologia">1</h1>
</div></div>

<div class="column mcb-column three-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
<div class="column_attr clearfix align_left box">
<h2 class="box-heading">BOX TITLE</h2>
<p class="box-text">TEXT</p>
</div></div>
```

And then have a toggle button/link to expand/collapse this:

```
<div class="more-first" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="column mcb-column one-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
<div class="column_attr clearfix align_right">
<h1 class="passos-metodologia">2</h1>
</div></div>

<div class="column mcb-column three-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
<div class="column_attr clearfix align_left">
<h2 class="box-heading">BOX TITLE</h2>
<p class="box-text">TEXT</p>
</div></div>

<div class="column mcb-column one-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
<div class="column_attr clearfix align_right">
<h1 class="passos-metodologia">3</h1>
</div></div>

<div class="column mcb-column three-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
<div class="column_attr clearfix align_left">
<h2 class="box-heading">BOX TITLE</h2>
<p class="box-text">TEXT</p>
</div></div>
```

And the CSS, in case it helps:

```
.column {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 1% 40px;
}

.column-margin- .column {
   margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
.column_attr.align_right {
   text-align: right;
}
.column_attr.align_left {
   text-align: left;
}
.one-fourth.column {
   width: 23%;
}
.three-fourth.column {
   width: 73%;
}
.passos-metodologia {
   color: white;
   margin-top: .4em;
   font-size: 10em;
}
.box {
   background: #353535;
   padding: 0 5%;
   max-width: 42em; 
   margin-left: 1.8em;
}
.box-heading {
   color: white; 
   text-align: right; 
   margin-top: 1em;
}
.box-text {
   color: white;
   text-align: justify;
}
```

I´ve came across plenty of jQuery demos but they all maintain the toggle button ABOVE the expanded content.

As you can see in the html, this is not a list, but the output looks like one.
So, I don´t want to "break" the list by having a toggle button in between 1 and 2 after the content has been expanded.

I need the toggle button/link to move down WITH the content so that I have this:

**Before expanding:**

1- Content 
(toggle link)

**After expanding:**

1- Content 
2- Content 
3- Content 
(toggle link)

**Additional info:**

I ran into a similar problem regarding the toggle position once the content is expanded and this pen did the trick: https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA/

However, in that situation, all I had was TEXT!
Now I have plenty of div´s within div´s.

So the script found on the pen above does not apply anymore as it triggers based on the amount of characters it is supposed to display before it shows the toggle link.

How can I translate exactly what that pen does when I´m trying to expand/collapse multiple nested div´s instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the content you want to show/hide inside a div, but close the div above the last part that you want to "slide" down.

```
<div class="more-first" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="column mcb-column one-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
  <div class="column_attr clearfix align_right">
  <h1 class="passos-metodologia">2</h1>
  </div></div>

  <div id="hideMe" style="display:none">

    <div class="column mcb-column three-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
    <div class="column_attr clearfix align_left">
    <h2 class="box-heading">BOX TITLE</h2>
    <p class="box-text">TEXT</p>
    </div></div>

    <div class="column mcb-column one-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
    <div class="column_attr clearfix align_right">
    <h1 class="passos-metodologia">3</h1>
    </div></div>
  </div> <!-- close the div of hidden content -->

  <!-- this content will slide down when the above is shown -->
  <div id="myclickDiv" class="column mcb-column three-fourth column_column  column-margin-">
  <div class="column_attr clearfix align_left">
  <h2 class="box-heading">BOX TITLE</h2>
  <p class="box-text">TEXT</p>
  </div></div>
</div> <!-- close outer div-->
```

Then use javascript / jQuery to toggle it:

in some JS file, or within script tags:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#myclickDiv ).click( function()
  {
      // use toggle(), or for explicit control: show() and hide()
      $( "#hideMe" ).toggle(400); //animate and show/hide it
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Aaron. Thanks for your reply. In the example above I used 3 content boxes just for the sake of example. I actually have 7. So, in that case I´d do just the same? Closing the show/hide div at <h1 class="passos-metodologia">7</h1> and the remaining last block out of it? Sorry, I´m still finding my way around jQuery... would you mind providing a full script or something else into context?

Comment: I updated the code with a full jQuery example.  I also added an ID to the div to select on.  That makes all the contents of that div clickable.  If you just want the text to be clickable, you can move the ID to the h2 tag or wherever you'd like.